# Cleaning up Magento Modman symlinks

Tags: magento

I have a made a mess of my Magento installation using modman and now I have hundreds of unused symlinks scattered over the source code.

How can I remove these symlinks and clean up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to simply remove all symlinks run the following from the web root:

```
 find . -type l -exec rm {} \;
```

If you want to remove all symlinks and have have modman re-create only those that should be 
there then:

```
modman repair
```